# How can I view queries used for .create or .save without executing

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to be able to retrieve the SQL statement being executed when calling

```
MyModel(**kawrgs).save()
```

or

```
MyModel.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

But without actually creating the object in the database. I already know I can access queries via `django.db.connection.queries`and `querysetobject.sql`, and I guess using transactions in some way may be useful, but seems this is a bit over my head.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

A.

Answer (score 0):

You could figure out what method is called in the inner workings of `save()` or `create()` to run the final sql statement against the database (probably something in the db backend like `cursor.execute()`) and use the mock library to prevent it from being executed and capture it's arguments instead.